# Categorize rows as first, last or in between

Tags: sql, oracle, case, categories, oracle12c

[image]

I have a table called `road_events`.

```
  create table infrastr.road_events 
   (
    event_id number(5,0),
    road_id number(5,0),
    event_type nvarchar2(50),
    lifecycle_number number(5,0)
   );

insert into infrastr.road_events (event_id,road_id,event_type,lifecycle_number) values (1,100,'CONSTRUCTION  ',1);
insert into infrastr.road_events (event_id,road_id,event_type,lifecycle_number) values (2,100,'CONSTRUCTION  ',2);
insert into infrastr.road_events (event_id,road_id,event_type,lifecycle_number) values (3,100,'INSPECTION',2);
insert into infrastr.road_events (event_id,road_id,event_type,lifecycle_number) values (4,100,'INSPECTION',2);
insert into infrastr.road_events (event_id,road_id,event_type,lifecycle_number) values (5,100,'INSPECTION',2);
insert into infrastr.road_events (event_id,road_id,event_type,lifecycle_number) values (6,100,'INSPECTION',2);
insert into infrastr.road_events (event_id,road_id,event_type,lifecycle_number) values (7,200,'INSPECTION',0);
insert into infrastr.road_events (event_id,road_id,event_type,lifecycle_number) values (8,200,'CONSTRUCTION  ',1);
insert into infrastr.road_events (event_id,road_id,event_type,lifecycle_number) values (9,200,'INSPECTION',1);
insert into infrastr.road_events (event_id,road_id,event_type,lifecycle_number) values (10,200,'INSPECTION',1);
insert into infrastr.road_events (event_id,road_id,event_type,lifecycle_number) values (11,200,'CONSTRUCTION  ',2);
insert into infrastr.road_events (event_id,road_id,event_type,lifecycle_number) values (12,200,'INSPECTION',2);
insert into infrastr.road_events (event_id,road_id,event_type,lifecycle_number) values (13,200,'INSPECTION',2);
insert into infrastr.road_events (event_id,road_id,event_type,lifecycle_number) values (14,200,'INSPECTION',2);
insert into infrastr.road_events (event_id,road_id,event_type,lifecycle_number) values (15,200,'CONSTRUCTION  ',3);

select
    event_id,
    road_id,
    substr(event_type,0,15) as event_type,
    lifecycle_number
from
    infrastr.road_events
order by
    event_id

  EVENT_ID    ROAD_ID EVENT_TYPE      LIFECYCLE_NUMBER
---------- ---------- --------------- ----------------
         1        100 CONSTRUCTION                   1
         2        100 CONSTRUCTION                   2
         3        100 INSPECTION                     2
         4        100 INSPECTION                     2
         5        100 INSPECTION                     2
         6        100 INSPECTION                     2

         7        200 INSPECTION                     0
         8        200 CONSTRUCTION                   1
         9        200 INSPECTION                     1
        10        200 INSPECTION                     1
        11        200 CONSTRUCTION                   2
        12        200 INSPECTION                     2
        13        200 INSPECTION                     2
        14        200 INSPECTION                     2
        15        200 CONSTRUCTION                   3
```

For each road, I would like to categorize the rows in each lifecycle with a `lifecycle_name` (in this order):

1. The rows in the last(max) lifecycle would be called `current lifecycle`

If there is more than 1 row per lifecycle, then:

2. The rows in the first(min) lifecycle would be called `original lifecycle` (if applicable)
3. Any others would be called `past lifecycle` (if applicable)

It would look like this:

```
+----------+---------+----------------+------------------+--------------------+
| EVENT_ID | ROAD_ID |   EVENT_TYPE   | LIFECYCLE_NUMBER |   LIFECYCLE_NAME   |
+----------+---------+----------------+------------------+--------------------+
|        1 |     100 | CONSTRUCTION   |                1 | ORIGINAL LIFECYCLE |
|        2 |     100 | CONSTRUCTION   |                2 | CURRENT LIFECYCLE  |
|        3 |     100 | INSPECTION     |                2 | CURRENT LIFECYCLE  |
|        4 |     100 | INSPECTION     |                2 | CURRENT LIFECYCLE  |
|        5 |     100 | INSPECTION     |                2 | CURRENT LIFECYCLE  |
|        6 |     100 | INSPECTION     |                2 | CURRENT LIFECYCLE  |
+----------+---------+----------------+------------------+--------------------+
|        7 |     200 | INSPECTION     |                0 | ORIGINAL LIFECYCLE |
|        8 |     200 | CONSTRUCTION   |                1 | PAST LIFECYCLE     |
|        9 |     200 | INSPECTION     |                1 | PAST LIFECYCLE     |
|       10 |     200 | INSPECTION     |                1 | PAST LIFECYCLE     |
|       11 |     200 | CONSTRUCTION   |                2 | PAST LIFECYCLE     |
|       12 |     200 | INSPECTION     |                2 | PAST LIFECYCLE     |
|       13 |     200 | INSPECTION     |                2 | PAST LIFECYCLE     |
|       14 |     200 | INSPECTION     |                2 | PAST LIFECYCLE     |
|       15 |     200 | CONSTRUCTION   |                3 | CURRENT LIFECYCLE  |
+----------+---------+----------------+------------------+--------------------+
```

Is there a way to succinctly categorize the rows as described?

I can think of some lengthy/cumbersome ways to do it with `case` statements and subqueries, but I'm looking for something a bit more elegant than that.

Comment: How do you consider it as lengthy/cumbersome before writing it? What is the query you have come up with?

Comment: Without a `case ... when` statements I see two other options that will also qualify as  lengthy/cumbersome since you think that `case` does. It would be using with or a subquery with unions defining the max and min to join the principal query

Comment: @Wilson . . . And how do you define when a lifecycle begins?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Well, as you might have noticed, we don't always have a record of the initial construction event of a road. Therefore, the lifecycle of the road begins at the first known record of the road. It could be `construction` or it could be an `inspection` of an existing road. The `LIFECYCLE_NUMBER` field is based on a date field, but I didn't include the date field because I didn't think it was relevant.

Comment: The date field is relevant, 100%. In the MATCH_RECOGNIZE solution I proposed, you can order by the date column (not field!) instead, and skip a step in your overall code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One other option without a `CASE` statement is to use `decode`.

```
with EVENTS
     AS (SELECT event_id,
                road_id,
                SUBSTR(event_type, 0, 15)  AS event_type,
                lifecycle_number,
                MIN(lifecycle_number)
                  over (
                    PARTITION BY road_id ) min_val,
                MAX(lifecycle_number)
                  over (
                    PARTITION BY road_id ) max_val
         FROM   road_events)
SELECT event_id,
       road_id,
       event_type,
       lifecycle_number,
       DECODE(lifecycle_number, min_val, 'ORIGINAL LIFECYCLE',
                                max_val, 'CURRENT LIFECYCLE',
                                'PAST LIFECYCLE') LIFECYCLE_NAME
FROM   EVENTS
ORDER  BY event_id;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d409c/8)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `match_recognize()` clause for a concise and efficient solution:

```
select event_id, road_id, event_type, lifecycle_number, lifecycle_name
from   road_events
match_recognize(
  partition by road_id
  order     by lifecycle_number
  measures  case classifier() when 'A' then 'ORIGINAL LIFECYCLE'
                              when 'B' then 'PAST LIFECYCLE'
                              else          'CURRENT LIFECYCLE'
            end  as lifecycle_name
  all rows per match
  pattern   ( ^ a+ b* c d* $ )
  define    a as lifecycle_number  = first(lifecycle_number),
            c as lifecycle_number != prev(lifecycle_number),
            d as lifecycle_number  = prev(lifecycle_number)
);
```

NOTE: Thanks to @MT0 for catching a mistake in an earlier version - see comments below this Answer for details.

Comment: I have failed to get an intuitive  grasp of  this `match_recognize`, even after couple of years!. Still trying.

Comment: @KaushikNayak - `match_recognize` is a nice combination of features of analytic functions (partition by and order by work just like in analytic functions) and regular expressions with regard to recognizing patterns in a sequence of rows (rather than in a sequence of characters). There are a few good articles about it online. That, and practice (here on SO)!

Comment: This only appears to return the first 6 rows of the OP's test data.

Comment: @MT0 - You are right. Thank you for catching that. I tested on modified data (I wanted to make sure it works correctly in other cases) and I didn't catch my mistake: the last bit of the `PATTERN` clause must be `d*` rather than `d+` (the CURRENT STATUS may apply to just one row, it doesn't have to be two or more rows). Corrected now.